# Issues getting the number of weeks between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

This function of mine returns a massive amount of weeks that doesnt make sense

```
 getWeeksToDate(){
        var current_date = new Date();
        console.log(current_date) //Sat Jan 11 2020 17:07:30 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) 
        console.log(new Date(555555558555)); //Mon Aug 10 1987 02:59:18 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [I did set this randomly for the test]
        var seconds_to_date = (new Date(current_date) -new Date(555555558555) ) 
        var weeks_to_date = seconds_to_date/60/60/24/7;
        console.log("semanas vividas:" +Math.ceil(weeks_to_date));
        //Returns lived weeks to date rounded to upper number
        return Math.ceil(weeks_to_date); //returns 1691805 weeks, which doesnt make sense since its around 32445 years, when it should equal to around 33 years
    }
```

Comment: That diff returns the diff in milliseconds. Milliseconds / 1000 = seconds. Then chain your operations (/60/60/24/7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Date(...) - new Date(...)` returns the timestamp in *milliseconds*. Thus, you need to additionally divide by 1000 to convert the milliseconds into seconds.

```
var weeks_to_date = seconds_to_date/1000/60/60/24/7;
```